# Links in d3.js tooltips don't work for MobileSafari (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, d3.js, treemap

I've tried everything to get simple links working in d3.js tooltips in MobileSafari. I'm using a treemap, and my code looks like this:

```
if (iOS == true)  {
      html += "<div style='z-index:50;'><a href='" + data.TearsheetLink + "'>Go to tearsheet</a></div>"; 
        }
```

This causes a link to appear only when an iOS browser is detected (obviously), but clicking on the link does nothing except make the tooltip disappear. I've also tried using onclick.

It's very strange because if I press and hold on the link in MobileSafari, I can select "open in new page," and it will work. But simply clicking the link does nothing. I've also tried adding target='_blank', but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it might be some sort of mouseout trigger or something similar that's getting triggered in iOS. On Desktop browsers, mousing over the treemap square shows the tooltip, but on iOS, tapping the square brings up the tooltip. The original problem was that tapping one square brought up the tooltip, but then tapping another square automatically activated the link instead of again bringing up the tooltip; so I disabled iOS clickthrough with `if (iOS == false) 
  
  {
  domElement.onclick = function(){ window.open(data.TearsheetLink);
         
   }`